# Что если обернуть тип массива в скобки при выделении памяти?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, delete

Стандартный способ выделить массив из 5 элементов - так:

```
int *a = new int[5];
```

ну и удаляется он

```
delete[] a;
```

А что если добавить скобки?

```
int *b = new (int[5]);
```

Круглые скобки заставляют выделять один объект, являющийся массивом из 5 элементов, а не массив из 5 элементов. Это подтверждается сообщением об ошибке при попытке подставить переменную в размер массива (где `d=`):

http://codepad.org/BvHyTPs6

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int *a = new int[5];
  int *b = new (int[5]);

  int n = 5;
  int *c = new int[n];
  int *d = new (int[n]);

  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> In function 'int main()':
> Line 12: error: ISO C++ forbids variable-size array
> compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
> ```

Чем массив `b` отличается от массива `a` и как правильно освободить за собой память, выделенную таким образом?

```
delete b;
```

или всё-таки

```
delete[] b;
```

и почему?

А может через такой указатель вообще удалять нельзя, потому что его тип отличается от типа выделенного объекта?

Кстати, на ideone аналогичный код компилируется, как и обычный variable-size array: https://ideone.com/MGmBya. Этот факт как-то влияет на освобождение памяти?

---

Также выяснилось, что компилятор не хочет выводить константность размера из такого объявления https://ideone.com/XwtTMQ & http://codepad.org/p3VKqMvd

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <size_t n> void f(int a[n])
{
  cout << n << endl;
}

int main()
{
  f(new (int[5]));
  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> prog.cpp:12:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(int*)’
>    f(new (int[5]));
>                  ^
> prog.cpp:5:26: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int n> void f(int*)’
>  template <size_t n> void f(int a[n])
>                           ^
> prog.cpp:5:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> prog.cpp:12:17: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘n’
>    f(new (int[5]));
>                  ^
> ```

Тогда возникает вопрос, почему та же конструкция с переменной - это VLA, а с константой - простой указатель.

Comment: @vegorov, а давай подробнее?

Comment: Интересно бы понять, кто прав :) - VC++ спокойно съедает переменную в таком выражении. И - imho, понятно - нужен таки `delete[]`, поскольку вызов деструкторов при просто `delete` не пройдет (по крайней мере в VC++).

Comment: @Harry,  я думал, эти два new с конструкторами/деструкторами работают одинаково. Или нет?

Comment: @Kromster, ну так себе. Тут какой-то мутный массив. Для нормальных массивов надо использовать `delete[]` - это известный факт.

Comment: @vegorov, а я не знаю, но буду рад, если кто-то распишет это в ответе.

Comment: Правильный вариант `delete static_cast< decltype(new (int[5]) ) >(b);`, поскольку в операторе инициализации b был потерян тип указателя.

Comment: Могу только сказать, что на уровне ассемблерном выделение памяти в VC++ в обоих случаях совершенно одинаковое...

Comment: @Chorkov, а вот это похоже на правду.

Comment: @Chorkov, а почему это не компилируется? https://ideone.com/XwtTMQ & http://codepad.org/p3VKqMvd Разве он не должен был вывести 5?

Comment: Был неправ. Выражение `new (int[5])` имеет тип `int*` .

Comment: @Chorkov, что-то странно тогда. Если это int*, то почему проблемы с VLA?

Comment: В описании [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) есть такой пример: `new (int (*[10])()); // okay: allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions`, из чего я делаю вывод что то что в скобках может интерпретироваться как указание типа. В данном случае эти два варианта (`new int[5]` и `new (int[5])`) идентичны, и удаление должно быть `delete []b;`

Answer (score 3):

Ключевой момент, как уже заметил `@VTT` в комментариях:

> Круглые скобки заставляют выделять один объект, являющийся массивом из
>   5 элементов, а не массив из 5 элементов.

это неправда.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int ptr[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    auto p1 = new (ptr)(int[5]);
    auto p2 = new (int[5]);
    std::cout << p1[3] << std::endl;
    delete []p2; // ok
    delete []p1; // error
    return 0;
}
```

[new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) - вариант синтаксиса `(1)`, с указанием типа в скобках

То есть вы по прежнему выделяете массив из 5 элементов.

`::(optional) new (placement_params)(optional) ( type ) initializer(optional)` вот описание синтаксиса `new expression`, собcтвенно вы указываете тип в скобках. Вот здесь:

```
 auto p2 = new (int[5]);
```

Типом будет массив из 5 элементов. Это то же самое что написать

```
 auto p2 = new int[5];
```

только это уже второй вариант синтаксиса, когда тип указывается без скобок.

И во втором варианте (без скобок) вы можете в качестве первой размерности задавать переменную, которую можно привести к std::size_t, а в первом варианте так делать уже нельзя. То есть можно:

```
int n = 5;
auto p = new int[n][5];
```

Но нельзя

```
int n = 5;
auto p = new int[5][n];
auto p1 = new (int[n][5]);
```

> If type is an array type, all dimensions other than the first must be
>   specified as positive integral constant expression (until
>   C++14)converted constant expression of type std::size_t (since C++14),
>   but (only when using un-parenthesized syntax (2)) the first dimension
>   may be any expression convertible to std::size_t. This is the only way
>   to directly create an array with size defined at runtime, such arrays
>   are often referred to as dynamic arrays

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98851/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vegorov).

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну и что стало с обсуждением в чате? Как его посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор смотрит тип предоставленный оператору `new` и если этот тип является массивом, то возвращаемое значение будет указателем на первый элемент.

```
int * ip = new int[1];
```

`ip` имеет тип указателя на `int`, а тип `int[1]` - это уже массив.

Второй случай, где оператору `new` предоставлен тип не массив:

```
char * cp = new char ;
```

Здесь `cp` это указатель на `char`, а аргумент оператору тоже `char`.

Чтобы определить, как удалять память нужно сравнить типы `*указатель` и `аргумент new`.

При сложном случае, когда типы неизвестны (**typedef** или шаблон) можно воспользоваться сравнением типа с помощью **typeid**.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Os -std=c++11 newarr3.cpp
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C{
public:
int i;
C(){cout<<"C;";}
~C(){cout<<"~C;";}
};

typedef C A[5];
typedef C B[1] ;
typedef C D ;

int main()
{
  cout<<"auto  ap  = new A :"<<endl;
  auto  ap  = new A ;cout<<endl;
  cout<<"delete [] ap :"<<endl;
  //Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  //delete  ap  ;cout<<endl;
  delete [] ap  ;cout<<endl;
  cout<<"auto  bp  = new B :"<<endl;
  auto  bp  = new B ;cout<<endl;
  cout<<"delete [] bp :"<<endl;
  // free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)
  //delete  bp  ;cout<<endl;
  delete [] bp  ;cout<<endl;
  cout<<"auto  dp  = new D :"<<endl;
  auto  dp  = new D ;cout<<endl;
  cout<<"delete  dp :"<<endl;
  // free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)
  //delete [] dp  ;cout<<endl;
  delete dp  ;cout<<endl;
  cout<<"ap  = new A :"<<endl;
  ap  = new A ;cout<<endl;
  if  ( typeid(*ap)  ==  typeid(A)){
    cout<<"typeid(*ap).name == typeid(A).name == "<<typeid(A).name() <<"\n";
    delete  ap  ; }
  else{
    cout<<"typeid(*ap).name = "<<typeid(*ap).name() << " <> "<<
      "typeid(A).name = "<<typeid(A).name()<< "\n";
    delete  []  ap  ;}
  cout<<endl;
  bp  = new B ;  cout<<endl;
  if  ( typeid(*bp)  ==  typeid(B)){
    cout<<"typeid(*bp).name == typeid(B).name == "<<typeid(B).name() <<"\n";
    delete  bp  ; }
  else{
    cout<<"typeid(*bp).name = "<<typeid(*bp).name() << " <> "<<
      "typeid(B).name = "<<typeid(B).name()<< "\n";
    delete  []  bp  ;}
  cout<<endl;
  dp  = new D ;cout<<endl;
  if  ( typeid(*dp)  ==  typeid(D)){
    cout<<"typeid(*dp).name == typeid(D).name == "<<typeid(D).name() <<"\n";
    delete  dp  ; }
  else{
    cout<<"typeid(*dp).name = "<<typeid(*dp).name() << " <> "<<
      "typeid(D).name = "<<typeid(D).name()<< "\n";
    delete  []  dp  ;}
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Результат:

```
auto  ap  = new A :
C;C;C;C;C;
delete [] ap :
~C;~C;~C;~C;~C;
auto  bp  = new B :
C;
delete [] bp :
~C;
auto  dp  = new D :
C;
delete  dp :
~C;
ap  = new A :
C;C;C;C;C;
typeid(*ap).name = 1C <> typeid(A).name = A5_1C
~C;~C;~C;~C;~C;
C;
typeid(*bp).name = 1C <> typeid(B).name = A1_1C
~C;
C;
typeid(*dp).name == typeid(D).name == 1C
~C;
```

В вашем примере однозначно видны типы. Возвращаемый тип это указатель на `int`, а память выделяется на тип массива. Удалять нужно с помощью `delete[]`.

Comment: Если бы скобки игнорировались, не было бы ошибки про VLA.